# If - Cant add more "Then's"?

Tags: vba, excel

In the below code, only the first line after "Then" works - How do i add more "Then's"?

```
Sub Opgave2()
Dim tidligst As Date
tidligst = WorksheetFunction.Min(Worksheets("Base").Range("d2:d18288"))
For i = 2 To 18288
    If Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4) = tidligst Then Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 2) = tidligst
    Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12)
End If


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, tried it on the code as well, which didnt work out - Thats why im asking :)

Comment: Isnt that what the forum is for?

Comment: You did not get the If-ElseIf Code from Google?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement

Comment: That adds more "If's", i need more "Then's" imo?

Comment: You probably want `ElseIf` and `Else`. [MS Excel: How to use the IF-THEN-ELSE Statement (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

Comment: Please see the link that I posted :)

Comment: No. If my Conditions is = True, it should change several things, not just one :)

Comment: Then put it in one if-endif block. Please go through the link that I gave above and understand the syntax of  If-Endif

Comment: Your link shows how to make more "if's", not more Then's.. I need to make different things happen if my condition is true :)

Comment: So it says 
If Condtion is True -> Then XXXX and also Then XXXX and Then XXX

Comment: Just press enter after the `then` keyword in your code. I mean I don't know, @SiddharthRout I guess sometimes people just get stuck you know

Comment: But the thing is that, @siddharth does have a point, there are lots of examples on the web, **lots** of it. You could have tried yourself before posting this question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make multiple things happen in one `If...Then` statement, then add multiple statements to a single `Then` block. Follow this example from [Using If...Then...Else Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/using-ifthenelse-statements):

```
Sub AlertUser(value as Long) 
 If value = 0 Then 
 AlertLabel.ForeColor = "Red" 
 AlertLabel.Font.Bold = True 
 AlertLabel.Font.Italic = True 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Note the three lines of code in between the `Then` and `End If` keywords. All three will be executed when `value = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

**A)**
------ An If Then if all on one line is considered terminated

So

```
If Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4) = tidligst Then Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 2) = tidligst
```

Is complete as is. And you will get an End If Without Block If for your statement as below as the IF is already considered terminated

```
If Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4) = tidligst Then Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 2) = tidligst
        Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12)
End If
```

**B)**
------ To do multiple things within the IF

1) Use [If, ElseIf, Else,End If](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ifthenelse-statement) construct to test for multiple conditions and do different things according to which condition is met

2) Split your line after the Then to do multiple things within the one IF condition

```
If Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4) = tidligst Then 
        Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 2) = tidligst
        Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12)
End If
```

**C)**
------ With respect to your additional question:

IsEven is a worksheet function and in VBA you call it as the outside wrapper for the range. Also, you use AND operator not & concatenation to combine conditions.

```
ElseIf Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4) = tidligst And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsEven(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 5)) Then Worksheets("Tidligst Indskrevne").Cells(i, 5) = "XXX"
```

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes very good sense - But why are you not calling wether ISEVEN = True or false? How do you then write it for the false?

Comment: So when something evaluates to true you don't need to write  If x = True you simply write If x .....And for False you can write If Not x. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go on one line, you need several lines.

```
   Sub Button1_Click()
    If Range("A1") = "Hi" Then
        Range("A2") = "Low"
        Range("B1") = "Yep"
        Range("F3") = "Spinach"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - Can you tell me what is wrong with what i wrote below then?

Comment: If you have only one action to perform if a condition is met, you can just use one line, but if you have many actions to perform when a condition is met, then you need to put it in the format others and myself have shown you.